# Changing an URL hash from a form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On my index.html I have the following form:

```
<form action="/search" id="search-form">
    <input type="text" id="search-input" name="s" x-webkit-speech>
</form>
```

Which correctly redirects to `/search?s=searchvalue` but how could I change that to `/search#s=searchvalue` using javascript?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well not with jQuery but that should work:

```
<form action="/search" id="search-form"
      onsubmit="location.href=this.action+'#s='+this.s.value; return false;">
    <input type="text" id="search-input" name="s" x-webkit-speech>
</form>
```

See also this fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/SujwN/

Comment: Great answer! :D

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest:

```
$('#search-form').submit(
    function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var input = $('#search-input');
        window.location.hash = input.attr('name') + '=' + encodeURIComponent(input.val());
    });
```

The above, coupled with an `on('hashchange', /* other stuff... */)` listener seems to work:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(e){
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1),
        attrValue = hash.split('='),
        varName = attrValue[0],
        varValue = attrValue[1];
    console.log(varName, decodeURIComponent(varValue));
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/g3QTn/).

References:

- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`decodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent).
- [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).
- [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).
- [`submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/).
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).
- [`window.location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location).

Comment: Thanks for the solution and linking to the elements you used, I'll keep that in mind. I'll be using rekire's solution as it's simpler and requires less changes. I have jquery already linked on my site so a jquery solution was also accpeted. (Just in case you were wondering about the jquery tag).